# SQL for COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

This is my first experience posting a question in this site :) so, i´m in trouble. I have a database in access, that i connect with ODBC.

Database have 3 tables:

```
nombres : (-idnombre, -nombre)
rutas   : (-idruta, ruta)
fechas  : (-idfecha, idruta, idnombre, fecha)
```

Sample data :

```
nombres:(1,nombreA),(2,nombreB)
Rutas:(1,rutaA),(2,RutaB)
fechas:(1,1,1,28/06/2013), (2,2,1,28/06/2013), (3,2,2,28/06/2013),(4,2,2,28/06/2013)
```

so i need this output ( third field is a count  ):

```
rutaA - nombreA - 1 time
rutaA - nombreB - 0 times
rutaB - nombreA - 1 time
rutaB - nombreB - 2 times
```

my sql is:

```
SELECT rutas.ruta, nombres.nombre, Count(fechas.idruta) AS CuentaDeidruta
FROM rutas INNER JOIN 
    (nombres INNER JOIN fechas ON nombres.idnombre = fechas.idnombre) 
    ON rutas.idruta = fechas.idruta
GROUP BY rutas.ruta, nombres.nombre;
```

its ok, but is not showing zero counts. so my output is:

```
rutaA - nombreA - 1 time
rutaB - nombreA - 1 time
rutaB - nombreB - 2 times
```

I tried with left join, so i get some errors.

Comment: When you used `LEFT JOIN` what were the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `Cartesian Product` of Rutas and Nombres, thus giving you something like this as in your sample data, there is no correlation between rutaA and nombreB.

```
SELECT t.ruta, t.nombre, Count(fechas.idruta) AS CuentaDeidruta 
FROM (
    SELECT rutas.idruta, rutas.ruta, nombres.idnombre, nombres.nombre
    FROM rutas, nombres
  ) t
  LEFT JOIN fechas ON 
    t.idnombre = fechas.idnombre AND fechas.idruta = t.idruta
GROUP BY t.ruta, t.nombre;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db3b6/4)

This is for SQL Server, but should port over to MS Access pretty closely.  Also please note the usage of a `LEFT JOIN` to ensure you get the 0s you were missing.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Awesome!! i changed it a little for my purposes. it works ok. Great answer, and really very very fast (34 secs ). Thank you again :)

Comment: @Dav3 -- np, glad I could help!

Comment: one more little question. if i add a where ( for example : SELECT t.ruta, t.nombre, Count(fechas.idruta) AS CuentaDeidruta, t.idruta, t.idnombre, fechas.fecha
FROM [SELECT rutas.idruta, rutas.ruta, nombres.idnombre, nombres.nombre
    FROM rutas, nombres
  ]. AS t LEFT JOIN fechas ON (t.idruta = fechas.idruta) AND (t.idnombre = fechas.idnombre)
  WHERE fechas.fecha BETWEEN #25/05/2013# AND #30/05/2013#
GROUP BY t.ruta, t.nombre, t.idruta, t.idnombre, fechas.fecha; the 0s are missing once again. Its possible fix this ?

Comment: @Dav3 -- you'll want to add that criteria to your LEFT JOIN instead of the WHERE clause.  As soon as you add it to the WHERE clause, it negates the LEFT JOIN.